# TopBar in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, tabs, tabbar

I am learning swift but I have a problem.
I would like to make a top bar that covers the entire top of the screen. The problem is now I have an error that I do not understand: "Value of optional type 'CGFloat?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'CGFloat'"

I would like to have help thank you in advance

````
import Foundation

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            TopBar()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
struct TopBar : View {
    var body : some View{

        VStack(spacing: 20){
            HStack{
                Text("News").font(.system(size: 20)).fontWeight(.semibold).foregroundColor(.white)
                
                Spacer()

            }
        }.padding()
        .padding(.top, UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.safeAreaInsets.top + 10) //line with error : Value of optional type 'CGFloat?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'CGFloat'
        .background(Color("Color"))
    }
}```
````

Comment: but you do not need use safeAreaInsets, once you are inside VStack, you are in safe area! I believe you have problem in your design. you would need safeAreaInsets, when your View was maxed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `.last?` that question mark means that `last` may not exist -- so, you end up with an optional (`CGFloat?`) instead of a (non-optional) `CGFloat`.

You could use nil coalescing (the `??` operator -- https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-is-the-nil-coalescing-operator) to provide a default value in the event that your original value was nil:

```
.padding(.top, (UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.safeAreaInsets.top ?? 0) + 10)
```

However, you should be aware that SwiftUI does safe area padding for you -- you shouldn't actually need to do it yourself. If you want 10 pts of top padding below the safe area inset, just use `.padding(.top, 10)`

**Update, based on comments**:

```
struct TopBar : View {
    var body : some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            HStack{
                Text("News").font(.system(size: 20)).fontWeight(.semibold).foregroundColor(.white)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .background(Color.red.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top))
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work either or I misused your comment

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Still a syntax error?

Comment: no it's not a syntax problem it's visual, the result is not the expected one, the topbar doesn't go to the top of the iphone

Comment: Ah -- that's a different question entirely. Look up `edgesIgnoringSafeArea`

Comment: I tried ".edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)" but there is still a white stripe especially in the places with time, network and battery

Comment: Show your code using that so I can see how you're using it.

Comment: struct TopBar : View {
    var body : some View{

        VStack(spacing: 20){
            HStack{
                Text("News").font(.system(size: 20)).fontWeight(.semibold).foregroundColor(.white)
                
                Spacer()

            }
        }
        .padding()
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        .padding(.top, UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.safeAreaInsets.top ?? 0 + CGFloat(10))
        .background(Color("Color"))
    }
}

Comment: oups the code is not very beautiful seen like this

Comment: Check my update -- I'm guessing this will at least get you on the right track.

Comment: thank you very much for all your answers you have completely solved my problem

Comment: Great -- you can mark the answer as correct by clicking the green checkmark. Thanks